# Bevel is constrained to an axis

Tags: edges, faces

often while using blender at some point the "bevel" function becomes "bound" to an axis. For example, instead of smoothing an edge creating a new face oriented at 45° it remains relative uniquely to the Z axis, and the new face is flattened on it. Because the "preferred axis" is now Z, this happens with horizontal edges. Vertical edges behave normally.

Am I pressing some shortcut I should not press? Is this behaviour even normal?

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: Did you apply rotation and scale (CTRL + A)?

Comment: Uhm, what is that?

Comment: Press CTRL + A and select Apply Rotation and Scale. With object selected ofcourse.

Comment: That solved the problem, thank you. Although I don't know what happened exactly :)

Comment: Check docs for explanation: https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/User:Fade/Doc:2.6/Manual/3D_interaction/Transform_Control/Reset_Object_Transformations